# Torch Tutorial: meaning of "trainData.data[{ {},i,{},{} }]:mean()" in 1_data.lua

Tags: lua, torch

In the torch tutorial, I found the line:

```
mean[i] = trainData.data[{ {},i,{},{} }]:mean()
```

Is there anyone who can explain what the indexing { {},i,{},{} } is doing?
I could guess, but wanted to know the exact mechanism.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a concise syntax for tensor narrowing / slicing, detailed [here](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor--dim1dim2--or--dim1sdim1e-dim2sdim2e-) in the documentation.

Inside the `[{ ... }]`, you can for each dimension of a tensor:

- pass a number `n` to only keep the `n`-th component along this dimension,
- pass a range `{start,end}` to keep all the components from `start` to `end` along this dimension,
- pass `{}` to keep all the components along this dimension.

In this precise case, it's a narrowing from a `u * v * w * x` tensor to a  `u * 1 * w * x` tensor by keeping only the `i`-th component along the 2nd dimension.